# Prove that if f '(x) <= 1/2 for all x in the domain of f, then f has at most one fixed point.

Tags: calculus

I'm pretty sure we need to prove via contradiction, but in the past I've only ever had to prove that there exists at most a set number of roots.

Comment: I think you need to assume $\vert f'(x) \vert \le 1/2$; consider what happens if $f(x) < -\pi < 1/2$!

Comment: @Robert, I don't think so.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson:  right you are!